# How to return a substring from a text column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows, I would like to return name of the person only, example Will,Armstrong, from the 2nd column. How can I achieve this?

```
1. Will,Armstrong:similarity=99.8   2011-08-25 17:16:16
2. Tom,White:similarity=90.0        2011-08-24 16:25:15
3. Johnny,Thomas:similarity=80.0    2011-08-24 13:20:15
4. John,Broderick:similarity=70.0   2011-08-21 10:25:15
```

Thanks.

John

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT split_part(textcolumn, ":",1) FROM yourTable
```

You can use the one-based [`split_part`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-string.html) function. You should also consider normalizing your database by saving the name and the similarity in different columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
select split_part(col2, ':', 1) as name
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'anything up to colon (:)' you could use:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column2 FROM '^[^:]+') FROM table;
```

or

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column2 FROM 0 FOR POSITION(':' IN column2)) FROM table;
```

See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-string.html) for string functions in PostgreSQL.